# RAID versus Storage Pools

Tags: sql-server, raid, storage-spaces

I'm currently developing a requirements specification for a new server and am trying to weigh benefits & pitfalls with available technologies. Our current server uses a RAID-5 disc layout which failed hard recently, resulting in the loss off a fair bit of data.

Storage Pools/Spaces appear to be worth investigating from what I've read so far, however searching ServerFault has resulted in a few concerns being raised.

My question is, has the technology behind Storage Pools/Spaces progressed far enough that it is a viable option for enterprise level storage & serving of data, should I stick with RAID-5 or look into another RAID solution? My current preference would be to use RAID-10, however I'm not sure if I could swing this as a viable expense.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you tell us more about the use case for the server / needed iops, the amount of disks you are looking at, spinning or flash?

Comment: Storage spaces is by no means a cheap option to do it correctly. What the rest of your environment consists of in terms of hyper-v/vmware, sql etc will lead you down one path or the other

Comment: Also don't forget, RAID is not a backup.

Comment: Don't try to get too fancy for a single server just because you had a bad restore experience.  If you can't "swing" the expense of RAID 10 on a single server then you shouldn't even be concerning yourself with Storage Pools/Spaces.

Comment: @TheCleaner Most fancy setups I've seen came from trying to get more bang for your buck in smaller environments. I don't really understand your viewpoint when you say not being able to sell the cost of RAID-10 immediately removing the possibility of Storage Pools/Spaces...

Comment: @Jeroen: It'll most likely be around 8TB storage space consisting of spinning discs, possibly with a couple of SSDs thrown in for higher-demand applications. The size to number of disc ratio will depend on what will better suit the solution I present, 

Use-case is a MSSQL Server supporting around 13 medium-large sized sites with sporadic load, all data is backed up to tape on a per-day basis.

Comment: @Drifter104: The current MSSQL Server (Standard) runs straight off Windows on a physical server, not on a virtual machine.

Comment: IOPS for some of the databases I'm looking at moving over to the new server: [imgur link](http://imgur.com/owylKGM), database_id "2" is the current tempdb

Comment: @Reaces - my comment was somewhat tongue in cheek.  While "bang for buck" is fine, it's "big bang for big bucks" vs. a simple single server with RAID10.  I'm simply stating to the author that just because a server running RAID 5 died doesn't mean they should suddenly architect a higher end solution without mgmt. buy in, etc.  It sucks for the author to deal with a lost server and restore, but it happens.  Nothing wrong with looking into more robustness, but don't get caught up in a unicorn scenario.

Comment: @TheCleaner: I do appreciate the view & I agree with you that a knee-jerk reaction to abandon RAID-5 is just that, that's why I'm looking into as many options as I can before making a decision on the route to take. Unfortunately I know embarrassingly little about enterprise-level server management (being a developer) so all views are welcome & will be researched thoroughly.

Comment: i gotta say i can't recommend storage spaces any more, one minor error with the metadata and the whole storage pool is gone! and there are no tools from Microsoft that helps with the recovery!

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Storage Spaces became generally usable for most workloads starting with Windows Server 2012 R2. Before then, it was only worth the effort for specific workloads, like Hyper-V storage. With R2, performance is now on-par with other off-the-shelf SAN and RAID technologies. Monitoring still leaves a bit to be desired and some features like re-balancing are lacking. Windows Server 2016 brings Storage Spaces closer to feature parity with other SAN and RAID products.

If you don't already have something like Operations Manager in place to help you keep an eye on it, but you do have monitoring from your server vendor already then I recommend sticking with the RAID solution provided by your server vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Storage spaces has a fame to be really slow, so I advise you against using it for database storage. I suggest you to use a RAID 10 array instead.

Here you can find [some](http://thedocsworld.net/storage-spaces-performanceserver-2012/) [links](http://homeservershow.com/storage-spaces-performance-windows-8.html) about that.

**UPDATE:** it seems that with Win2012 R2 Storage Spaces is viable for **mirror** and **stripe** configuration. However, it remain very slow for anything involving parity RAID. [Here](http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/wp-windows-storage-spaces-performance-ww-en.pdf) you can find a Fujitsu's paper with full performance analysis.

Comment: This would offer a lot more with a source or two that shows storage spaces are slow.

Comment: I've edited the reply to include some links

Comment: Wow, those links are very old and the test bed is a home pc/server. They aren't something that should be used as a reliable source of information in an enterprise situation.

Comment: Those articles are test cases just post the beta phase, and one of them is for a home pc. I don't think they're still topical.

Comment: There are other tests on the net with same or comparable results. If you have other references, please post them here.

Comment: http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/wp-windows-storage-spaces-performance-ww-en.pdf complete break down of raid and various storage spaces designs

Comment: Here you can find a Fujitsu showcase of storage spaces: http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/wp-windows-storage-spaces-performance-ww-en.pdf As you can see, anything involving parity shows hw RAID being much master then storage spaces

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote:
I am not familiar with MSSQL, and I don't know if it is possible to run this on Linux. If it is not, you could consider making a VM for Windows on a Linux (or FreeBSD) hypervisor.*

You could consider running your disk controller in JBOD mode and use the Zettabyte file system (ZFS). With ZFS you can allocate some RAM and SSD's for read (ARC/L2ARC) & write (ZIL) caching. Besides that ZFS has its own "RAID" options, like raidz1-3 (1/2/3-parity) or just stripe over multiple mirrors (fastest, but less redundancy).

The advantage of ZFS is that it has its own consistency mechanisms, for example scrubbing, which ensures your data being consistent. You can have hot-spares, compression, dedup, etc.

I run ZFS for years now (FreeBSD) and it is really reliable. Alot of things happened, including broken disk-arrays, but ZFS always seems to recover.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have access to the discs, from what I've just learned we have a Storage Area Network that houses the data & our servers dip directly into that.